# How to reset model in Qt?

Tags: qt, model-view

I am using Qt model/view framework. When I reset the data in the model, I have to reset the model to let views update also. How to do it? I found a signal `modelReset(QPrivateSignal);` in the QAbstractItemModel, Is this the way to solve it? How to emit the signal? Thanks.

Comment: Worth to mention that there are other methods that help  to update views. All depends on what changes are made. Model reset is useful when you're performing big canges in model. There is `beginInsertRow`, `beginMoveRows`, `beginRemoveRows`. All those methods also apply to columns. So if you're going to perform small changes don't use `beginResetModel` as it will rebuild whole model in view instead of applying small changes on view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You call `beginResetModel()` before you reset your data, and then `endResetModel()` once you have finished.  The `endResetModel()` emits the private signal.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel), the preferred method is to use the `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` functions surrounding your reset code in your model subclass.

This should handle emitting the signal appropriately.

Some of the qabstractitemmodel subclasses might allow you to use `model.removeRows(0,model.rowCount())`  (others would require you to implement it yourself)